# Vending Machine function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration, javascript-objects

I'm very new to Javascript: I've been working with it for a few weeks casually now. This is my first post, so I apologize if I'm not thorough enough, but I think I have been below!

I want to create a function VendingMachine(snack, cash) that has a list of 4 items and their prices that takes 2 arguments, "snack name" (snack) and "cash inserted" (cash). I've tried making the list an object and an array and only have semi-success with the array, but I believe the object is truly the path I want to take because...

When using an array with nested arrays for the snacks list, the only problem is that if the for() loop  doesn't find the "snack" value in any of the arrays, it prints 'undefined' instead of "Sorry, try again."

With the list of items in the machine in an object, I want to check that "snack ==== object.KEY" and that "cash >= VALUE" of that KEY. My problem here is that I don't know the syntax concerning objects well, and the explanations and answers I see other people posting are too abstract for me to comprehend at the moment, or are more complex loops/problems and don't really seem to be applicable to my situation. All things except this (which I couldn't figure out either/didn't work):

```
 for(var key in objects) {
    var value = objects[key];
}

// Using an array

    function vendingMachine(snack, cash) {
    //declare nested arrays of snacks & costs
    var snacks = [
        ["Espresso", 1],
        ["Cappuccino", 2.50],
        ["Chocolate bar", 2],
        ["Potato Chips", 3.50]
    ]
    //iterate through array to match snack and check funds
    for (var i = 0; i < snacks.length; i++) {
        if (snack === snacks[i][0] && cash >= snacks[i][1]) {
            if (snack === "Potato Chips") {
                console.log("Your " + snack + " have been served");
            } else {
                console.log("Your " + snack + " has been served");
            }
        }
        else if (snack === snacks[i][0] && cash <= snacks[i][1]) {
            console.log("Insufficient funds. Please insert more cash.");
        }
    }
}


// Using an object (incomplete or perhaps just VERY incorrect, I'm aware, hence why I'm here to understand why!)

    function vendingMachine(snack, cash) {
    //declare nested arrays of snacks & costs
    var snacks = {
        "Espresso": 1,
        "Cappuccino": 2.50,
        "Chocolate bar": 2,
        "Potato Chips": 3.50
    }

    if (snack === snacks.hasOwnProperty() && cash >= snacks.key) {
        if (snack === "Potato Chips") {
            console.log("Your " + snack + " have been served");
        } else {
            console.log("Your " + snack + " has been served");
        }
    }
    else if (snack === snacks.hasOwnProperty() && cash <= snacks.key) {
        console.log("Insufficient funds. Please insert more cash.");
    }
    else if (snack != snacks.hasOwnProperty()) {
        console.log(snack + " does not exist. Please try again.") //returns undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using some modern javascript I have updated your vending machine and also made it return change.

```
function vendingMachine(snack, cash) {
    const snacks = [
        { name: 'Espresso', price: 1 },
        { name: 'Cappuccino', price: 2.50 },
        { name: 'Chocolate', price: 2 },
        { name: 'Potato', price: 3.50 }
    ];

    const selected_snack = snacks.find(item => item.name === snack);

    if (selected_snack) {
        if (selected_snack.price === cash) {
            return `Your ${snack} have been served`;
        }
        else {
            if (selected_snack.price > cash) {
                return `Insufficient funds. Please insert more cash.`;
            }
            else {
                return `Your ${snack} have been served. Here is your $${cash - selected_snack.price} change.`;
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        return `${snack} does not exist. Please try again`
    }
};

console.log(vendingMachine('Espresso', 12));
```

First of we convert the snacks into an array of objects, each one of them having a `name` and a `price` keys.

Next we use the [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to search the list of snacks for the snack in question by it's name. The function will return a single object, if you want multiple results that match some criterion use `Array.filter()` instead.

So if we have a match we can say `if (selected_snack)` which evaluates to `true`, otherwise if there is not match then `selected_snack` would be `undefined` so basically a less verbose way to say `if (selected_snack !== undefined)`.

The rest of the function is almost self-explanatory, the only changes I made is that I'm not console logging inside of the function, instead I am using a return statement.

Also in case you wonder what those weird looking ${} things are, check out about [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), extremely easy and convenient to use so you don't have to write ugly code such as `"Your " + snack + " have been served"`.

I hope that helps, if you have any questions let me know.

Comment: This is the best one! Amazing organization! I have not yet seen/learned about arrows. Where can I learn about 'item' and how to know what generic words like that I can use with certain methods to iterate through them or search for things? I am also working on another stereotypical program (a cipher) that I need to search through strings with and I'm horrible with string manipulation. This sort of thought-process seems to be right up the alley I need to do this type of looping/searching!

Comment: @ferret arrow functions are part of the modern javascript syntax or what you will often hear referred to as ES6 or later. `(item => item.name)` is basically the equivalent of writing `function(item) { return item.name }`, however there are a few small but very important differences which you will learn with time and from experience, namely that the `this` keyword. Don't worry if you don't understand this yet, but if you need a good article on arrow functions, [read this](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions-basics) and [this](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions) articles.

Comment: @ferret I was writing a response to your question before you edited your comment.  In response about the question about the `item`, it's not a generic word, you can substitute `item` with absolutely anything you want  (like `tomato` for example) and as long as it's valid or not a reserved javascript keyword then the function will work absolutely the same. Additionally, you can also add an index like this `(item, index) => ...` and then once it detects a second parameter you can reference the index alone or `array[index]` if you need that for whatever reason. Refer to the article I linked.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably create the list as array of objects as it give you flexibility when you need to add more details about snacks. So the list could be like

```
const snacks = [
  {
    "name": "Chips",
    "price": 123
  },
  {
    "name": "Drinks",
    "price": 456
  }
];
```

Now your vendingMachine function can be very simple which will find the matching snack and price. Something like this

```
function vendingMachine(name, price) {
  const canSnackBeServed = snacks.find(snack => snack.name === name && price >= snack.price);

  if (canSnackBeServed) {
    console.log("Your " + name + " has been served");
  } else {
    console.log("Snack doesn't exist or Insufficient funds.");
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This does help! I want to make three separate if/elseif statements as the instructions say to have different output if you have:
1) the correct snack and cash
2) the correct snack and insufficient cash
3) the snack simply doesnt exist (this is very different than having selected the right snack but not having enough and i want it to be specifically displaying these ideas)
I'll try separating the code out and get back to you soon :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to see exactly what is wrong with the code you have; I'd suggest one of the main problems might be how you're using `snacks.hasOwnProperty()`.

[`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) takes an argument which is a key, and it returns a boolean. So in your example, the code should probably look more like `snacks.hasOwnProperty(snack)`, which would check whether the `snacks` object has the property `snack`.

How you store the data is up to you, and you're fairly close to being able to get it to work. One thing to note is that `snacks.key` will attempt to get the `key` property of `snacks`, which is probably not what you wanted to do here. Instead, something like `snacks[snack]` might have been more appropriate. [You can use either dot notation or square bracket notation to get properties of objects.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

---

With all that being said, here's some code which might illustrate a few new concepts, hopefully without being too abstract. Don't worry too much about [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)s; they're basically the same as regular functions, just with a different syntax.

What I've setup below would allow you to have a generic function `getSnack`, which will determine which function it should use to get the correct snack data. This means that you don't have to worry about which way you've stored the snack data at the point of use.

From then on, the code is really quite similar to what you have; the other concept we have here is [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring), which is a fun one to learn, and can save a little on syntax.

Hopefully this helps, please ask away with any questions.

```js
const snacks = {
  "Espresso": 1,
  "Cappuccino": 2.50,
  "Chocolate bar": 2,
  "Potato Chips": 3.50
};

const snacksArray = [
  ["Espresso", 1],
  ["Cappuccino", 2.50],
  ["Chocolate bar", 2],
  ["Potato Chips", 3.50]
];

const getSnackFromArray = (array, itemName) => array
  .find(x => x[0] === itemName)

const getSnackFromObject = (snackDataObject, itemName) => (
  snackDataObject.hasOwnProperty(itemName)
    ? [itemName, snackDataObject[itemName]]
    : undefined
)

const getSnack = (data, itemName) => Array.isArray(data)
  ? getSnackFromArray(data, itemName)
  : getSnackFromObject(data, itemName)
  
const vendingMachine = (snack, cash) => {
  const snackData = getSnackFromObject(snacks, snack);
  
  if (snackData === undefined) {
    console.log(snack + " does not exist. Please try again.")
    return;
  }
  
  const [snackName, cost] = snackData;
  
  if (cash >= cost) {
    console.log("Your " + snack + " have been served")
  } else {
    console.log("Insufficient funds. Please insert more cash.")
  }
}

vendingMachine('Espresso', 1.1)
vendingMachine('Espresso', 1)
vendingMachine('Espresso', 0.9)
vendingMachine('Expresso', 0.9)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function vendingMachine(snack, cash) {
//declare nested arrays of snacks & costs
var snacks = {
    "Espresso": 1,
    "Cappuccino": 2.50,
    "Chocolate bar": 2,
    "Potato Chips": 3.50
}

if (snacks.hasOwnProperty(snack) && cash >= snacks[snack]) {
    if (snack === "Potato Chips") {
        console.log("Your " + snack + " have been served");
    } else {
        console.log("Your " + snack + " has been served");
    }
}
else if (snacks.hasOwnProperty(snack) && cash <= snacks[snack]) {
    console.log("Insufficient funds. Please insert more cash.");
}
else if (snack != snacks.hasOwnProperty(snack)) {
    console.log(snack + " does not exist. Please try again.") //returns undefined
}
```

}

Comment: this doesnt work, either. sorry - thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: @ferret https://jsfiddle.net/27xr96n8/ please check this fiddle